# Cancel a save of a list item, but still run the workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to cancel a save of a list item but still run the workflow. How would I go about doing this?

Example: I save an item in a list. It runs the workflow, but the save item does not appear in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function presaveaction(){
    modifyColumnToRunEditedWorkflow(ItemID);
    return false;        
}

function modifyColumnToRunEditedWorkflow(id){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("site");
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Title');
    var oListItem;
    oListItem = oList.getItemById(id);
    oListItem.set_item('ColumnToEdit', 'value');
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, updateListItemOK), Function.createDelegate(this, updateListItemError));
}

function updateListItemOK() {
    alert('Item updated and workflow is run');
}

function updateListItemError(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```